# openmpi doesn't compile : error: declaration does not declare anything

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I want to use MPI. I installed it with
 `sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev`

I included the header <mpi.h> in my code and when I try to compile, I have :

```
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/mpicxx.h:191,
                 from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/mpi.h:2868,
                 from main.cpp:6:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/ompi/mpi/cxx/constants.h:169:28: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
  169 | OMPI_DECLSPEC extern const Datatype COMPLEX;
```

I really don't know how to fix it since I don't want to modify the files in openmpi/include

EDIT :
@Gilles Gouaillardet made me notice that I may have done something like `#define COMPLEX` which was actually the case because I had a Complex class.
Changing the macro made my code compile.
The question now would be, how can we know which macro can we use ? Do we just need to avoid some "obvious" names as COMPLEX when we use some libraries, or is there a way to know which one we can use or not ?

Comment: please edit your question and post a [MCVE] (to confirm you do not do something like `#define COMPLEX`)

Comment: This is exactly what I did indeed. I did a ```define COMPLEX```. It works without.

Comment: There is no absolute rule about what to do and not. Prefixing all your macros can be a good practice though. But in this case, the right thing to do is to modernize your code and stop using MPI C++ bindings that were removed from the MPI standard more than a decade ago. plain `C` bindings are generally good enough, and you can have a look at `boost.MPI` (or other libraries) if you wished for something more C++-ish.